# How to initialize a TList<T> in one step using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics, generic-list

I am sure this is a easy question, but I cannot get it to run:

```
var
  FMyList: TList<String>;
begin
  FMyList := TList<String>.Create(?????);
end;
```

How to insert instead of ????? to insert this 3 strings:

> 'one'
>  'two' 
>  'three'

Thanks..

Comment: Create the list and then insert with FMyList.Add.

Comment: Yes, I am doing now in this way, but I would like to do that in one step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no single method to do this.  You could write your own constructor to do this as so:

```
constructor TMyList<T>.Create(const Values: array of T);
var
  Value: T;
begin
  inherited Create;
  for Value in Values do
    Add(Value);
end;
```

Then you could write:

```
FList := TMyList<string>.Create(['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

---

**Update**

As Uwe correctly points out in his answer, the code I present should use the `AddRange()` method:

```
constructor TMyList<T>.Create(const Values: array of T);
begin
  inherited Create;
  AddRange(Values);
end;
```

Comment: I was asking for a languaje-already-existant way of do it... But this is a good approximation in absence of this functionality...

Comment: @FerPt I know that's what you were asking for, hence my first sentence.

Comment: I have tried to get your approximation with Class Helpers... No luck..   Seems no way to use class helpers on generics...

:-(

Seems your answer is the only valid in Delphi XE.

Answer (score 17):

Not a one liner, but a two liner:

```
FMyList := TList<String>.Create;
FMyList.AddRange(['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

Edit: Of course you can combine it with David's approach.

Comment: +1 I'm not familiar with AddRange, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks Uwe, I think I cannot distribute the 'accepted answer' to David and you.  Both are good answers.

Thanks again.

Comment: I think two lines is better than one line here, and I deplore Constructor side effects.

Comment: And one line of variable declaration. And if it is the only variable : one line of **var** keyword. So something between 3 to 4 lines.